# Ubuntu 16.04 flickering and disappearing screen

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, login-screen, 16.04

Running Skylake/Nvidia GTX 950 on a clean install. I'm no expert at all and I haven't got a clue what to do. I've tried various things but nothing works and the guides are often not clear enough for newbies - if anyone can help me step by step I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Does this work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics

Comment: Yes it does! Many thanks. However I cannot see the launcher or menu bar in Ubuntu, I can only access things through the terminal. I haven't got a clue how to fix this. It is like they have vanished.

Comment: Do you have Unity (normal Ubuntu)?

Comment: I had this same issue after upgrading from 15.10->16.04 on my system different GPU (GTX 760) but perhaps the same will help you as worked for me the solution in my case was the following command:

sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz

Comment: Same issue here, some weird things are happening to my screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the Nvidia driver.

You can install it from the Addition Drivers application. (Dash > Additional Drivers.)

Choose the one marked as "tested".

Comment: 17.04, I have this problem also.  Definitely using the tested nvidia driver.  Only happens when I put my laptop in the dock -- it's fine the rest of the time.

Answer (score -1):

There might be something wrong with the driver. Go to the additional drivers app and install the NVIDIA driver.